# Angular Reactive forms set values with disabled attribute after form is initialized

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have created one form.

HTML Code :

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="name"/>
  <input formControlName="description"/>
  <input formControlName="category"/>
  <input formControlName="type"/>
</form>
```

Below is the code to initialize form, setting initial value as empty:

```
form: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
ngOnInit() {
  this.initForm();
}

private initForm() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      description: [''],
      category: ['', Validators.required],
      type: ['',  Validators.required],
  });
}
```

On certain condition the form needs to be filled with data received form a API. Once the data is received below code is executed :

```
// data received from API
if(data){
 this.form = this.fb.group({
  name: [{value: data.name, disabled: true}],
  description: [{value: data.description, disabled: true}],
  category: [{value: data.category, disabled: true}],
  type: [{value: data.type, disabled: true}]
 });
}
```

In above case, values are getting updated correctly, but the controls are not getting disabled.

I also tried setValue:

```
this.form.setValue({
  name: {value: data.name, disabled: true},
  description: {value: data.description, disabled: true},
  category: {value: data.category, disabled: true},
  type: {value: data.type, disabled: true}
});
```

In above case, the values are filled with [object Object].

How can I set the field value and set disabled attribute at same time?

Comment: To set value and disable at once, you could try `name: [{value: data.name, disabled: true}, Validators.required],`

Comment: your code works, see an stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p1f7mx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html, you only need take care if the "form" has no value, using in .html `<form *ngIf="form"...>` to avoid initial errors

Comment: @Eliseo, Thanks, adding ngIf="form", fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just `setValue` and disable the whole form?

```
this.form.setValue(data);
this.form.disable();
```

Comment: Thanks, I also thought of doing this. I wanted to know whether we can achieve this at once (setting the value and disabling the control).